# How do I do Authentication in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I recently started learning symfony and was faced with the task of making authentication. For example, in Laravel, authentication is done using various packages, where login, registration, password reset, and so on are automatically generated. Are there any similar packages for symfony? Otherwise, the standard registration, which is described in the documentation for the framework, is too simple.

Comment: what do you mean with "too simple"?

Comment: Take a look at the 'bin/console make' commands.  Besides make:user and make:auth there is also a make:registration-form and make:reset-password.  The used to be a bundle called FOSUserBundle but it was poorly maintained and demonstrated that trying to make a one-size fits all user management system does not often work well.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony has documented a great tutorial on setting up authentication. Even with Laravel it is not a one command and done process. This will take a little work, reading and understanding.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

This same process I use in every new Symfony application I develop.